# Optimize my search and copy code

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I have an Excel project which has a few thousand rows containing strings which need sorting out.
Typically one cell in each row should have a six digit number 123456 but many are 123456/123456/234567 etc. which need to have the / deleted and then be separated onto individual rows. There is other information in the surrounding columns which needs to stay with these six digit numbers.

I decided to approach this by firstly making copies of the rows the appropriate number of times and then deleting the surplus information

This code below deals with the copying part and it works.. but it's really slow. Is there a quicker way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for any help.

Chris

```
Sub Copy_extra_rows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

s = 2
Do Until s = Range("N20000").End(xlUp).Row

'checks for / in Mod list

    If InStr(1, Range("N" & s), "/") Then

'determines number of /

    x = Len(Range("N" & s)) - Len(Replace(Range("N" & s), "/", ""))

'loops x times and copies new row

        For a = 1 To x
        Range("J" & s & ":O" & s).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("J" & s + 1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        s = s + 1
        Next a

    Else
    End If
s = s + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: can you show a screenshot what your column N actually looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I would have approached this differently to optimize the process and improve the overall efficiency of code.

Firstly, I would load the entire column into an array. This way it's always faster to access the elements of that array rather then referring `Cells()` multiple times in loops. Working with objects in memory is much faster because your client doesn't need to for example update the UI. Generally, arrays big O is O(1) which means you instantly can access an object/data stored at a specific index.

Let's consider an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

[image]

Then the code (*Note: I have added comments in the code in the right places, hopefully that helps you understand what is going on)

```
Sub Main()

    Dim columnArray As Variant

    ' create an array from Range starting at L2 to the last row filled with data
    columnArray = Range("N2:N" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim c As New Collection
    ' add separate 6 digit numbers to the collection as separate items
    ' iterate the columnArray array and split the contents

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In columnArray
        If NeedSplitting(element) Then
            Dim splittedElements As Variant
            splittedElements = Split(element, "/")
            Dim splittedElement As Variant
            For Each splittedElement In splittedElements
                c.Add splittedElement
            Next
        Else
            c.Add element
        End If
    Next

    ' print the collection to column Q
    PrintToColumn c, "Q"

End Sub

Private Sub PrintToColumn(c As Collection, ByVal toColumn As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' clear the column before printing
    Columns(toColumn).ClearContents
    ' iterate collection and print each item on a new row in the specified column
    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In c
        Range(toColumn & Range(toColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = element
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function NeedSplitting(cell As Variant) As Boolean
    ' returns true if the cell needs splitting
    If UBound(Split(cell, "/")) > 0 Then
        NeedSplitting = True
    End If
End Function
```

After running the code all your numbers should appear as separate elements in column Q

[image]

NOTE: Why use a `Collection`?

`Collection`s in VBA are dynamic. It means you don't have to know the size of a collection in order to use it - unlike arrays. *You can re-dim your array multiple times to increase its size but that's rather considered a bad practice*. You can add *nearly* as many items to a Collection as you want with a simple `Collection.Add` method and you don't have to worry about increasing the size manually - it's all done for you automatically. In this scenario the processing happens in memory so it should be much quicker then replacing cells contents inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim s As Integer
Dim splitted_array() As String
s = 2 'Assuming data starts at row 2
Do Until Range("N" & s).Value = vbNullString Or s >= Rows.Count
    'Split the array
    splitted_array = Split(Range("N" & s).Value, "/")
    If UBound(splitted_array) > 0 Then
        'Set the first value on the first row
        Range("N" & s).Value = splitted_array(0)
        For i = 1 To UBound(splitted_array)
            'Add subsequent rows
            Rows(s + i).Insert xlDown
            Range("J" & s + i & ":O" & s + i).Value = Range("J" & s & ":O" & s).Value
            Range("N" & s + i).Value = splitted_array(i)
        Next
    End If
    s = s + 1 + UBound(splitted_array)
Loop
```

This code turns this:

[image]

into this:

[image]